# how to merge arrays and keep the repeaters

Tags: java, arrays, merge

So i want to merge arrays and keep any repeating numbers and also want to keep them in order form low to highest. I'm new to this so i don't know much and thanks for the help.

here is a example

array 1 = 1,2,2,3,8,9

array 2 =3,4,8,9

merge result = 1,2,2,3,3,4,8,8,9,9

another example

array 1 = 1,1,2,7,9

array 2 = 2,9,10,15

merge result = 1,1,2,2,7,9,9,10,15

if you need anything else just ask me and i will try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to approach the problem is to break this problem into smaller parts:

1. Combine two arrays into a single (new) array
2. Sort the new array into ascending order (i.e. lowest to highest)

Given `arr1` and `arr2` are some `int[]` variables with numbers that may or may not repeat, you can combine the two arrays by creating a new `int[]` array with length of `arr1.length + arr2.length` and then copying the values over.  A newbie to Java arrays will benefit from manually iterating using `for` loops, but the `System.arraycopy` method is also good once you're familiar with arrays:

```
int[] combo = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
{
    combo[i] = arr1[i];
}
// or replace the loop with System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, combo, 0, arr1.length);
for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
{
    combo[arr1.length + i] = arr2[i]; // the index is offset by arr1.length to avoid overwriting the previous values from arr1
}
// or System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, combo, arr1.length, arr2.length);
```

To sort the new array into ascending order, the built-in `Arrays.sort` will work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
Arrays.sort(combo);
```

Documentation on how `System.arraycopy` works can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
int[] combined = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
System.arrayCopy(array1, 0, combined, 0, array1.length);
System.arrayCopy(array2, 0, combined, array1.length, array2.length);
Arrays.sort(combined);
```

You create a bigger array with the memebers unsorted, then you sort them... ;-)